# Showing $SU(N)$ matrices commute with conjugate transpose

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, linear-algebra

$SU(N)$ is the group of all $N\times N$ matrices that satisfy

$$ \mathbb{U}^\dagger\mathbb{U}=1~~,\quad\text{and}\qquad \det \mathbb{U}=1~~.  $$

Denoting the $\mu$-row and $\nu$-column entry in $\mathbb{U}$ as $U^\mu_\nu$, the unitarity constraint may be written as

$$ \mathbb{U}^\dagger\mathbb{U}=1\quad\implies\quad \big( U^\dagger \big)^\nu_\mu U_\nu^\lambda=\delta_\mu^\nu~~.  $$

I assume that the unitarity constraint is such that

$$  \mathbb{U}^\dagger\mathbb{U}=1\quad\iff\quad  \mathbb{U}\mathbb{U}^\dagger=1~~,  $$

and I want to demonstrate this with the index algebra, and I am seeking input on whether or not there's a better way to show it.  I will take the indexed expression and multiply from the right with $U^\mu_\sigma$, then assume the commutivity, and obtain a true expression as

\begin{align}
 \mathbb{U}^\dagger\mathbb{U}=1\quad\implies\qquad\qquad \big( U^\dagger \big)^\nu_\mu U_\nu^\lambda&=\delta_\mu^\nu\\
 U^\mu_\sigma\big( U^\dagger \big)^\nu_\mu U_\nu^\lambda&=U^\mu_\sigma\delta_\mu^\nu\\
\left[U^\mu_\sigma\big( U^\dagger \big)^\nu_\mu \right]U_\nu^\lambda&=U^\mu_\sigma\delta_\mu^\nu\\
\text{Assume }U^\mu_\sigma\big( U^\dagger \big)^\nu_\mu=\delta^\nu_\sigma\quad\implies\qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \delta^\nu_\sigma U_\nu^\lambda&=U^\mu_\sigma\delta_\mu^\nu\\
U^\lambda_\sigma&=U^\lambda_\sigma~~.
\end{align}

I don't like it that I assumed $U^\mu_\sigma\big( U^\dagger \big)^\nu_\mu =\delta^\nu_\sigma $ in verifying this for myself.  What is a better way for me to convince myself that

$$  \mathbb{U}^\dagger\mathbb{U}=1\quad\iff\quad  \mathbb{U}\mathbb{U}^\dagger=1~~?  $$

When I try to use $(\mathbb{U}^\dagger\mathbb{U})^\dagger=1^\dagger$, the identity $(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$ does not let me cast the unitarity constraint in the desired form $\mathbb{U}\mathbb{U}^\dagger=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $U^\dagger U = 1$, you get $U^\dagger = U^{-1}$; then $UU^\dagger = UU^{-1}= 1$. You don't have to worry about anything; $\det U = 1$, this matrix is invertible.

Comment: Yes, the inverse is what I was missing.  Thanks.